# how to convert a JSON API returns an object to an array for using .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am trying redux-thunk for the first time Hence working on a simple project the thunk uses the API and displays the data on the screen but the API is returning a JSON object ,to display the titles on the screen I need to use the .map() function to map through the object, but the object doesn't allow us to use map() function so I need to convert the JSON data to an array and the use .map() function to achieve the desired result but I don't know how to convert the JSON data to an array
I tried different approaches to deal with this but nothing seems to work for me Here is what I need

```
const codeReturnedFromJSONRequest ={data:{0:somedata}} //example JOSN data
```

what I want my code to look like :

```
const requiredData=[{data:{0:somedata}}] //I want the required data to be an array so that I can use .map()
```

If you want my actual code here it is

```
 //ApiSlice

import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts/getPosts", async () => {
  return fetch("https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?q=naruto&sfw").then((response) =>
    response.json()
  );
});
const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState: {
    posts: [],
    loading: false,
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [getPosts.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getPosts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.posts = action.payload;
    },
    [getPosts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
    },
  },
});

export default postSlice.reducer
```

```
 //store

import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import postReducer from "./anime";

export const store =configureStore({
  reducer: {
    post:postReducer
  }
})
```

```
//Api data

  import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getPosts } from "../store/anime";

function Apidata() {
  const { posts, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.post);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, []);
  console.log(posts.data)
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((item) => (
        <h2>{item.data}</h2>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Apidata;
```

```
  // App.js
 import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
  import Apidata from "./components/Apidata";
  function App() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Apidata/>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }

  export default App;
```

Comment: what does the response look like if there is more than one returned? `{data:{0:blah, 1:foo}}` ?

Comment: Keep in mind that JSON is an object, so you can't have `[{data:{0:somedata}}]`. If you want an array inside a JSON, you will need something like `{array_data: [{data:{0:somedata}}]}`

Comment: yeah I tried the second approach i made something like in the place of ```post:[]``` I added something like ```post:[data:{}]``` and tried to puch JSON inside ```post.data``` but I was getting an error saying

Comment: react_devtools_backend.js:4026 A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.0`. Value: Promise {<pending>}[[Prototype]]: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This peace of code resolved my issue

```
const myObj = {0 : {mal_id: 20, url: 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/20/Naruto', images: 'test', trailer: 'test', approved: true}, 1: {mal_id: 20, url: 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/20/Naruto', images: 'test', trailer: 'test', approved: true}};

const myArr = [];

for (const key in myObj) {
    const arrObj = myObj[key];
  arrObj['id'] = key;
    myArr.push(arrObj)
}

console.log(myArr);
```

Click here to see the reddit post:

[Solution reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/xlxjes/how_to_convert_a_json_api_returns_an_object_to_an/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 1):

if you want create an array just wrap the response.json() in an array like that:

```
     export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts/getPosts", async () => {
      return fetch("https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?q=naruto&sfw")
.then(response=>response.json())
.then((response) =>[response]
      );
    });
```

BUT I don't think it is a best practice. Ask to whom create the backend and get explanations!.
Hope the best for you,
Mauro

Comment: i tried but now i am getting an error saying

Comment: react_devtools_backend.js:4026 A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.0`. Value: Promise {<pending>}[[Prototype]]: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: Object

Comment: sorry I think is because I forget a second .then(). I updatet the code above. .then(response=>response.json())
.then((response) =>[response]